# how to order by date in WP_Query ?

Tags: mysql, wordpress, sql-order-by

I have tried this way but **orderby** and **order** not working on WP_Query class

```
$posts = new WP_Query(
array(
    'post_type'=> 'block_code', 
    'orderby'=> 'post_date', 
    'order' => 'DESC'
    )
);
```

always it return **orderby=> 'menu_order'** and **order='ASC'**.

Note: if i use param in url as **orderby=date&order=ASC** then it works fine But i need as argument of WP_Query.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can set multiple parameters for **orderby** in your **WP_Query()**. Like **date**,**title**,**menu_order** etc.

Here is the [Order & Orderby Parameters](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_query/#order-orderby-parameters)

**Try this example**

```
$params = array(
    'post_type' =>'block_code',
    'orderby'   => array(
      'date' =>'DESC',
      'menu_order'=>'ASC',
      /*Other params*/
     )
);
$query = new WP_Query($params);
```

This example working properly for me in WP **Version_4.x**

Comment: I had already solve the problem in this this way, Thanks @sumon :) :)

Comment: Thank you too @tarikul05

Answer (score 2):

According to the docs to show posts ordered by date you should use `date`.(But the default is date anyway)

*"orderby (string | array) - Sort retrieved posts by parameter. Defaults to 'date (post_date)'. One or more options can be passed."*

```
     'orderby'=> 'date',
```

To show posts associated with certain type these are the valid types.So you must use on of them

- 'post' - a post.
- 'page' - a page.
- 'revision' - a revision.
- 'attachment' - an attachment. Whilst the default WP_Query post_status
  is 'publish', attachments have a default post_status of 'inherit'.
  This means no attachments will be returned unless you also explicitly
  set post_status to 'inherit' or 'any'. (See post_status, below)
- 'nav_menu_item' - a navigation menu item
- 'any' - retrieves any type except revisions and types with
  'exclude_from_search' set to true.
- Custom Post Types (e.g. movies)

https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query

Comment: have tried 'orderby'=> 'date' but not working for me

Comment: WP_Query('orderby=date&order=DESC')  Does this work for you?

Comment: It's working but without **post_type** value less for me, if i add **post_type** then it's not working

Comment: For post type block_code have you made a separate template page ? for displaying the page ?

Comment: What is block_type in the first place?if it is a custom post type you should first create it.But that is another question...Ordering by date has nothing to do with that...

Comment: yes @George block_type is custom post type. yes already created it. there already have data. and not working orderby and order

Comment: Have you used register_post_type() function to add it?

Comment: Also from the docs "Note that you must call register_post_type() before the admin_menu and after the after_setup_theme action hooks. A good hook to use is the init hook.".Well how to register a custom post type correctly is the topic of another question like I told you....

Comment: I used CPT Plugins for Custom post type, and it's working well for all functionality. only the orderby and order not working @George