# sort wp posts by custom date

Tags: php, wordpress, date

So I gave to each of my posts a custom date field ('data_evento') in format: d/m/Y.

The goal: sort the post this custom date. The most recents on top.

I tried a few online methods, **but** I could not make any of them actually work in my wordpress code (so I am not reposting any).

I look for help, starting from the default code I got in my template now, which is:

```
<?php
/* Start the Loop */
while ( have_posts() ) :
    the_post();
?>
    <div class="col">
        <?php get_template_part( 'template-parts/content-home', get_post_type() ); ?>
    </div>
<?php
endwhile;
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: use `WP_Query` then sort it by your criteria https://stackoverflow.com/a/39839722/3859027

Comment: You code is not using the custom date. I need to resort by custom date...

Comment: With the date format you have, this won't be trivial to do with WordPress APIs. It is possible, but you'll have to hook [posts_pre_query](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/posts_pre_query/)  alter the ORDER BY clause of the database query. If you can change your date format in your metadata to yyyy-mm-dd you'll have a much easier time.

Comment: I can change the date format into yyyy-mm-dd. More precisely, I have two options (using ACF plugin): Display Format and Return Format. I can change either or both of them. to yyyy-mm-dd if needed

Answer (score 0):

**Solved.**

```
<?php
      $query = new WP_Query
      (array(
        'meta_key' => 'data_evento',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'order' => 'ASC',
        'meta_query' => array(
                array(
              'key' => 'data_evento',
              'compare' => '>',
              'value' => date("Y-m-d"),
              'type' => 'DATE'
            )
       ),     
       ));

       while ($query->have_posts()): $query->the_post(); ?>
         // My posts 
<?php endwhile;?>
```